# How to retroactively add git commit history to display in Github

Tags: git, github

I know there are similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they are not exactly what I'm looking for.

I worked on a repo for about a year. When I checked the contributors page in Github: `https://github.com/company-name/repo-name/graphs/contributors`, it shows only 1 commit, which is not the case.

I was able to figure out that this is because I didn't have a global `~/.gitconfig` file for some reason. I created the file, added my name and my email, and now when checking the above url I finally started seeing new commits. However, my entire previous year of contributions are not displayed there.

Is there a way to retroactively display all commits on this github page?

Comment: You'll have to modify your entire history to apply your name and email to all your commits. Follow the instructions on posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi).